# How to add video background as a banner using Laravel?

Tags: html, css, laravel, sass

I'm trying to add a background video as a banner using Laravel ,  i have tried many options , this is what i  tried already :

```
<header class="header">

<div class="banner">

<video autoplay muted loop>



<source src="img/banner.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>

</div>

<div class="top-nav container">





<div class="logo">My website</div>



<ul>



<li>


[<a href="#">Shop</a>][1]

[<a href="#">About Us</a>][1]

[<a href="#">Contact</a>][1]

[<a href="#">Blog</a>][1]

</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

And that's what I have tried, but then I don't know how to make it's width  to fit in my website, because is showing up to big and I can't make it any smaller with scss

Answer (score 0):

I depends upon what type of background you want to put in your website. If you are going to use static image then you don’t need to worry about Laravel, you can do it from simple HTML & CSS. If you are talking about dynamic image, then you need to fetch it from the database.

For simple static image you can do as below in your css code:

**background-image:url('img/my_image.jpeg');**